# HTML Content Width

Tags: html, css

I need help changing the size of this [html content](http://cydia.death2020.net/depiction/aicon.php)? I need it to be a width of 300 the width is to wide for mobile use.

Comment: What have you tried...what is the code that generates the page.  Your question shows no effort on your part that you've attempted to solve this yourself.

Comment: google.com > SO 90% of the time

Comment: Please be more specific on what you are trying to do and the platform (iOS developed with XCode or some "HTML5 To iPhone" platform, like PhoneGap).

Comment: This isn't being displayed on a mobile browser just an application this application matter of fact. http://cydia.saurik.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the width of the body to 300px;

```
<body style="width: 300px;"></body>
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this will really solve your problem. I don't think iPhones are 300px wide for one. Also you need to adjust them for landscape and portrait layout and retina display. You need to use media queries for that. Edit- Nevermind, I just saw you other comment about the usage.